# Asking Boss to match salary.. again

Tags: management, salary

Here is the situation. I was Working on a sales job about 5 months ago and I landed a huge client for our company and so we received a big contract from them. I approached my boss about a raise because of this contract and because I had another job offer (and based on past performance) and I received a significant raise in my salary. Today, I have received a job offer from a company that pays 15% more, better benefits, new environment, new experiences, etc, and I am excited about it. However, I also really like my current job. The manager made it known that my first raise came with some strings. One of which was my next raise won't be for 12 months. I didn't think this was all that fair but I understood. This was not in any contract but verbal.

And so I am stuck on how to approach my boss about this. I am not asking what I should do. I already know I am going to approach him and let it him know that I have another offer. I am unsure how to put this across. He made it known I would not get another raise for 12 months when I received my first raise, but I think it is wise to at least bring it up to him.

Some clarity: If my current company matched the job offer, I would stay. If they came close to it, I would stay. If they don't move at all and are firm on the 12 month deadline, I'll leave.

My question: How do I bring this up to my employer in the best way without burning bridges? I'm afraid that even if he does match it, he won't trust me because I could be seen as constantly looking to leave. And second, he might see this as me using leverage for a second time to get a higher salary.

EDIT:
The big contract is the one I currently work on everyday. Unfortunately if I left, they would not renew (im the only one at our company who knows their finances left and right). I wish this was not the case but it is. My employer knows this as well, which makes it feel like blackmail. Yes I could train someone in the financial aspect, but this is a large client with relationships I have developed and they would easily move on to someone else.

Thank you

Comment: Companies deal with employees that leave all the time.  You shouldn't allow the potential future renewal of this contract to figure into whether you leave or stay.

Comment: "He made it known I would not get another raise for 12 months when I received my first raise, but I think it is wise to at least bring it up to him." It is wise to let him know your word counts for nothing?

Comment: @pmf I don't agree that the question insinuates that OP gave any word to keep

Comment: "Today, I have received a job offer from a company that pays 15% more.."did you apply for this position, or did the offer drop out of the sky?

Comment: Pretty much out of the sky

Comment: @pmf I meant I believe it is wise to bring the other offer to him. If I don't bring the offer to him, I automatically leave with zero chance of staying.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to approach this situation as a professional, who sells your time, for their money.

You're being offered better money. The 'no more raises for twelve months' is a perfectly reasonable condition in my opinion (perhaps you should have asked for a larger raise at the time to counter-act that).

You don't have any obligation to employer to keep working for them. The raise they gave you pays for the work you do week to week. When you stop working for them, they stop paying you.

Now it would be possible to tell your employer about the offer and ask for a second raise - but if I were the employer, I wouldn't give it to you. You could then just leave after a couple of months anyway.

Probably the best thing to do is to just leave, without suggesting a counter offer.

Your current employer will be ok, the walls won't collapse as you leave.

In response to your edit: it's not your fault if your boss has structured his business such it's reliant on one key employee. If that is the case - he should have offered you equity.

But maybe it a reasonable case to say: 'Look, I know that this is a a key client. I've been offered this other role that I'm considering taking - maybe we can discuss equity or a payrise'. A payrise only would take you back to that original point - what would stop you from leaving in two months? As far as I see - either equity or a (highly paying) binding contract that commits you to twelve months is the only real solution here, from your employer's perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Employers should be paying their staff based on their results.

Two types never to skimp on:  Those that design/make your products (clothing designers / software developers or anything creative) and salespeople.  They should *ALWAYS* be paid based on the value they bring.  (Now by salesperson, I mean someone who goes out and finds opportunities and closes them, not someone who answers website submissions.)

They are *NOT* functionaries.  They are not the same "thing" as a bookkeeper, an admin assistant, or a line worker.  These are the people who literally create value out of thin air.

Pay them for what value they create, or they will create it for someone else.

Always remember that when you're a creative talent or a salesperson.

Comment: I fundamentally agree with you 100%. I believe pay raises represent added value. As long as you keep adding value ( ex. Money through contracts) then you should continue to receive raises unless a contract was signed saying otherwise. I believe this is what frustrates me most.

Comment: "... or they will create it for someone else."

Comment: While I agree with you, I feel obligated to point out that you don't actually answer the question.